# Using abp-page-toolbar and abp-extensible-table

Tags: abp

I am trying to use both components in my angular application. I am a backend developper and absolutely newbie in angular. I have been reading the roles and users components in the source code and I think I cloned it for my Customers component. I have guards, defaults and all the code like Roles and Users but, although the code compiles and the API call is done, I have nothing in the screen, only the Total records are displayed. No action buttons, no table rows, no pagination...

Is there anyone who has use these components and can bring me some help?

Many thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Those components are needed for customizing built-in modules. Let's talk about `Users` for example. The `Users` component is a built-in page and you do not have access to its code. However, you may still need to make some changes like adding a `New User` button on the toolbar or changing its columns, form fields etc. That's why ABP Framework provides some injection tokens to override/extend/customize these features. Since you are developing your own page, you do not need any of this. You can directly use `ngx-datatable` in your own component, add or remove columns and so on.